# War file deployed on EC2 apache tomcat throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.general.GeneralUtilities.getWeakHashClock

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets, amazon-ec2

I have uploaded a war file to EC2 instance with Apache Tomcat running 8.0.41 version. I have a simple get request which returns text response. But when I invoke the get call, I'm getting the following error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gENs1.png)

But when I deploy the same war to my local instance of tomcat, its working perfect. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you have multiple versions of the same library in your WEB-INF/lib directory. It can be a lottery as to which version of a class gets loaded in this situation.

Comment: I have these 3 libraries. hk2-api-2.4.0-b25.jar, hk2-locator-2.4.0-b25.jar, hk2-utils-2.4.0-b25.jar

Comment: Is it possible that different versions of these jars are also present in the Tomcat "lib" directory? The line that says `org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.<init>(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1154)` is not from `hk2-locator-2.4.0-b25.jar`. The content `org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl` in this jar looks a lot different.

Comment: @SteveC, when I extracted the war file and looked at it, there were multiple versions of the same jar files. I removed the old versions and only used the latest jars and that resolved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were multiple versions of the same jar file. I removed the old versions and only used the latest jars and that resolved the issue.